# how to store setTimeout id on mongodb database?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, settimeout

I am using NodeJs with express and I want to store the id of setTimeout to a database so that I can use clearTimeout later I am currently using below code for this

```
var timerId = setTimeout(function(){
   console.log(id);
}, 100)

clearTimeout(timerId)
```

this code is just working fine but timerId contain an object that's why I am unable to store it on the database is there any other way to do so or is there way to convert the object which acceptable by MongoDB

this is the object which i get on printing timerId

```
Timeout {
_called: false,
_idleTimeout: 5000,
_idlePrev:
 TimersList {
 _idleNext: [Circular],
 _idlePrev:
  Timeout {
    _called: false,
    _idleTimeout: 5000,
    _idlePrev: [Circular],
    _idleNext: [Circular],
    _idleStart: 5876,
    _onTimeout: [Function],
    _timerArgs: undefined,
    _repeat: null,
    _destroyed: false,
    [Symbol(asyncId)]: 252,
    [Symbol(triggerAsyncId)]: 250 },
 _unrefed: false,
 msecs: 5000,
 nextTick: false,
 _timer: Timer { _list: [Circular] } },
_idleNext:
 Timeout {
  _called: false,
  _idleTimeout: 5000,
  _idlePrev: [Circular],
   _idleNext:
     TimersList {
      _idleNext: [Circular],
     _idlePrev: [Circular],
     _unrefed: false,
     msecs: 5000,
    nextTick: false,
    _timer: [Timer] },
 _idleStart: 5876,
 _onTimeout: [Function],
 _timerArgs: undefined,
 _repeat: null,
 _destroyed: false,
  [Symbol(asyncId)]: 252,
 [Symbol(triggerAsyncId)]: 250 },
_idleStart: 6029,
_onTimeout: [Function],
_timerArgs: undefined,
_repeat: null,
_destroyed: false,
[Symbol(asyncId)]: 316,
[Symbol(triggerAsyncId)]: 0 }
```

and what i want to do that i have three API

1. join-request
2. accept-request
3. reject-request

the user send the join request to join-request api then i maintan an array on database which contain all join requsts then admin accept and reject the request from that logs but what i want i want is if admin did not accept or reject the the request that request was automaticlly reject after some time

and for doing this thing i run an settimeout on join-request api and if admin accept or reject the requst i clear that settimeout and if it does not accept or reject the requset then my settimeout runs amd reject that request automaticlly

but the problem is that for clearing the settimeout i need settimeout id which i am unable to save please tell my if there is any way to acheive this

thanks in advance

Comment: I'm pretty sure that there is another better way to do whatever you want to do without store a setTimeout's id in a database.

Comment: can you give me any sugesion regarding this or tell me some better way to do so

Comment: I suggest explain your problem and what do you want to do.

Comment: i explain my problem above please give me a way to do this

Comment: No, you've asked how to execute the solution to your problem that you've already decided upon.  There has to be a reason that you're trying to start and stop a timer via an API, if you explain the underlying goal you're trying to achieve we can help you better.

Comment: @Paul i explain that what iwant to do with settimout please help me with this

Comment: See the answer by @F.Bernal, it's exactly what you want to do.  Far more reliable and scalable than what you're currently attempting.  Also, as a side-note, you will probably want to lengthen the interval.  Checking for expired join requests every 100 milliseconds is unlikely to be necessary even in the largest websites.  I would have thought checking once a minute would be aggressive and maybe once every hour is sufficient in most cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*the user send the join request to join-request api then i maintan an array on database which contain all join requsts then admin accept and reject the request from that logs but what i want i want is if admin did not accept or reject the the request that request was automaticlly reject after some time*

**Here you only need to store in the database a timestamp that your request occurs.**

*and for doing this thing i run an settimeout on join-request api and if admin accept or reject the requst i clear that settimeout and if it does not accept or reject the requset then my settimeout runs amd reject that request automaticlly*

**Then you only need to manage that timestamp.**

If the user request must not be shown to the admin only show request pending inside an interval of time.

If the request state must be shown to the user who perform the request, manage the request state by the timestamp when the user, rejecting the requests outsize the confidence interval (this can be done with Admin too.)

Comment: +1 this is what I was going to recommend as well.  To add to it, you can also pull the process that checks expired requests into a totally different process, perhaps managed by a cron job or the like, rather than trying to constantly check inside the web app.

Answer (score 1):

The above-mentioned code should work fine and should return a numeric. But, I don't think its a good idea to store the `ID` in DB. Even though I don't know your exact use case, what you are trying to do, I guess is to `clearTimeout` before the actual timeout happens. But since `setTimeout` is a runtime timer and gets killed as soon as the app exits its runtime, it's better to keep the `ID` in runtime than in a DB as it will be obsolete after the `n second` timeout that you have set.

Hope this helps !!

Answer (score 0):

timerId is just a number. You can store it directly to MongoDB.

Comment: timerId is not a number i console it and it return an object

Comment: Are you sure, because I just tried the above code on chrome console and it just spitted out a number

Comment: It is a number, but it has no sense store it in a database.